# SetAdditionalOptions is not working in Magento2.3.1

Tags: magento2.3.1, checkout-page, serialize, additional-options

I am facing a weird problem with **setAddtionalOptions** for checkout. Following is my code to set options using observer.

This is my `event.xml` file, which calls the observer to set additional options.

```
<event name="catalog_product_load_after">
      <observer name="set_additional_options" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Observer\SetAdditionalOptions"/>
</event>
```

This is observer file `Observer/SetAdditionalOptions.php`

```
class SetAdditionalOptions implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone,
        Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface $serialize,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->timezone = $timezone;
        $this->serialize= $serialize;
        $this ->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // Check and set information according to your need
        if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add') {
            //checking when product is adding to cart

               $additionalOptions[] = array(
                 'label' => "Created at",
                 'value' => $this->timezone->date()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
              );
             $observer->getProduct()->addCustomOption('additional_options', $this->serialize->serialize($additionalOptions));

        }
   }
}
```

The same code is working in 2.3.0 without issue but when I try the same code 2.3.1 it is not allowing me to checkout and also not giving any error in the log.

It is calling and adding created at date in cart item but when I try to checkout, it will redirect to cart page without any issue. If i remove following line then checkout will work fine:

```
$observer->getProduct()->addCustomOption('additional_options', $this->serialize->serialize($additionalOptions));
```

Is it a bug or something else?

Comment: Can you try to add log in the file to check whether your file is getting triggered or not or in which situation it is getting failed.

Comment: It is calling and adding created the date in cart item but when I try to checkout, it will redirect to cart page without any issue. If i remove following line then checkout will work:

 $observer->getProduct()->addCustomOption('additional_options', $this->serialize->serialize($additionalOptions));